# How to parse xs:annotation from the xs:choice using the System.Xml.Schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I'm trying to add the annotation element inside the xs:choice. According to the xs:choice syntax, this could be possible. I could not find the sample of choice with annotation inside  BTW. My current version of xsd file contains an element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/simple"
             elementFormDefault="qualified"
             xmlns="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/simple"
             xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:flex="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/flexBase">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/flexBase" />
    
    <xs:element name="ESS3754">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <flex:ControlHeadline>Headline_VVVVV</flex:ControlHeadline>
                        <flex:helpText>HelpText_VVVVV</flex:helpText>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="String1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

However, while parsing the xsd file, the Annotation of the object `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaChoice` is always null.

The code part:

```
public List<FSBaseItem> Parse( XmlTextReader xsdReader )
        {
            try
            {
                // prepare schema set for schema validation and raw template xsd "enrichment"
                XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
                schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationCallbackOne;

                // include base schema
                XmlSchema baseXsd = FlexXmlSchemaReader.ReadBase();
                schemaSet.Add( baseXsd );
                
                // The Read method will throw errors encountered on parsing the schema
                XmlSchema xsd = XmlSchema.Read( xsdReader, ValidationCallbackOne );
                schemaSet.Add( xsd );
                
                // The Compile method will throw errors encountered on compiling the schema
                schemaSet.Compile();

                // create root
                FSElement rootElement = new FSElement( this.GetNewId() );
                // traverse body
                this.TraverseSOM( xsd, rootElement );
                // validate
                this.ValidateFSItems( rootElement.Items );
                // init lists containers with minimum elements
                InitEmptyFEListItems( rootElement );                

                return rootElement.Items;
            }
            finally
            {
                xsdReader.Close();
            }
        }
```

Already in the beginning the choice element annotation is null. Could somebody give some working sample or add some hints?

Comment: You'd probably get better help if you show how you're parsing.  Please provide an [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: This xsd is correct except for one thing.. missin attribute name on the complexType. .. Can you add a detailed example?

Comment: @Xstian, no, the XSD is not correct even if the `xs:complexType/@name` attribute is added (which, btw, we cannot be sure is the context -- this could be part of an enclosing `xsl:element` declaration).  A `xs:schema` element is also missing, and namespace definitions for prefix 'flex' and 'xs' are missing too.

Comment: @kjhughes I mean that the complex type is correct... obviously the prefix are not declared. This is only an example, infact i asked if is possible to add more details.

Comment: @kjhughes: the post updated, with complete xsd and the parsing implementation.

Comment: @Vytas999 No, it's still not complete. Please refer again to the link in the first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotations certainly can be put inside xs:choice. Look at the following xsd taken from [Inline Annotated Schema](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
  jaxb:version="1.0" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <xjc:superClass name="com.syh.Shape"/>
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="Widgets">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:property name="Shapes"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="Rectangle" type="Rectangle"/>
                <xs:element name="Square" type="Square"/>
                <xs:element name="Circle" type="Circle"/>
            </xs:choice>
         </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Rectangle">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Width" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="Height" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Square">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Length" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Circle">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Radius" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Adapting similar strategy to your xsd yields something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/simple"
             elementFormDefault="qualified"
             xmlns="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/simple"
             xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:flex="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/flexBase">

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/flexBase" />

  <xs:element name="ESS3754">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <flex:ControlHeadline>Headline_VVVVV</flex:ControlHeadline>
            <flex:helpText>HelpText_VVVVV</flex:helpText>
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="String1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
        <xs:element name="NewlyAdded" type="Coordinate" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>    
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="Coordinate">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="LocationX" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="LocationY" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="LocationZ" type="xs:integer"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>    

</xs:schema>
```

and the xsd is perfectly valid and looks like the following in Visual Studio [XSD] Desginer:

[image]

**Update 1**

I agree on the fact that debugger shows item annotation as null [I could not find it either but I should] and it is quite frustrating. I reconstructed the document using the code and you can annotate your element using the following workaround:
Consider the following XSD which does not have any XmlSchemaChoice and is saved as stack-problem2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/simple"
             elementFormDefault="qualified"
             xmlns="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/simple"
             xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:flex="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/flexBase">

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/flexBase" />




  <xs:complexType name="Coordinate">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="LocationX" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="LocationY" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="LocationZ" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>  
</xs:schema>
```

Now you can load this into memory and add annotations programmatically to the XmlSchemaChoice element:

```
public void Parse()
{
    try
    {
        XmlTextReader reader2 = new XmlTextReader(@"stack-problem2.xsd");
        XmlSchema myschema2 = XmlSchema.Read(reader2, ValidationCallback);


        var simpleAnotation = new XmlSchemaAnnotation();
        simpleAnotation.Id = "Lost Anotation";

        // <xs:complexType name="ESS3754">
        XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = new XmlSchemaComplexType();
        myschema2.Items.Add(complexType);
        complexType.Name = "ESS3754";

        // <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        XmlSchemaChoice choice = new XmlSchemaChoice();
        complexType.Particle = choice;
        choice.MinOccurs = 1;
        choice.MaxOccurs = 1;

        XmlSchemaElement elementSelected = new XmlSchemaElement();
        choice.Items.Add(elementSelected);
        elementSelected.Name = "String1";

        AnnonateMyComplexType(choice); 

        FileStream file = new FileStream(@"satck-solution.xsd", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter(file, new UTF8Encoding());
        xwriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        myschema2.Write(xwriter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

public static void AnnonateMyComplexType(XmlSchemaChoice xmlSchemaComplexType)
{

    XmlSchemaAnnotation myCustomAnnotation = new XmlSchemaAnnotation();
    xmlSchemaComplexType.Annotation = myCustomAnnotation;

    // <xs:documentation>State Name</xs:documentation>
    XmlSchemaDocumentation schemaDocumentation = new XmlSchemaDocumentation();
    myCustomAnnotation.Items.Add(schemaDocumentation);
    schemaDocumentation.Markup = TextToNodeArray("Headline_VVVVV");

    // <xs:appInfo>Application Information</xs:appInfo>
    XmlSchemaAppInfo appInfo = new XmlSchemaAppInfo();
    myCustomAnnotation.Items.Add(appInfo);
    appInfo.Markup = TextToNodeArray("Headline_VVVVV");

}

static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
        Console.Write("WARNING: ");
    else if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
        Console.Write("ERROR: ");

    Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
}
```

Running above will return the following XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/simple" xmlns:flex="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/flexBase" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/simple" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.es.de/es3/flex/flexBase" />
  <xs:complexType name="Coordinate">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="LocationX" type="xs:integer" />
      <xs:element name="LocationY" type="xs:integer" />
      <xs:element name="LocationZ" type="xs:integer" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ESS3754">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Headline_VVVVV</xs:documentation>
        <xs:appinfo>Headline_VVVVV</xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:element name="String1" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

So to answer your first question: Yes, Annotation can be definitely put inside XmlSchemaChoice elements (Both through code and directly) [Not necessarily outside xmlSchemaChoice as the top element based on your experiment] and to address your second problem: [I had similar experience as of yours! It shows the annotation as null although it is not]

Comment: However, I still cant get it parsed. In this case, the {System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType} has a property "ContentTypeParticle", which is of type {System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaChoice}, but the Annotation of the choice is null as always. You can try to use XmlSchema.Read(..) and You will see.

Comment: The Schema itself is correct however Annotation elements are kind of an exception and little bit confusing. Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950785.aspx and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400185/xmlschema-reading-annotation-at-schema-level Questioner has similar problem as of yours.

Comment: @MHOOS, very helpful.  I recommend that you add an excerpt from the MSDN link to your answer as it likely contains the essence of OP's issue more so than whether XSD allows annotations under choice (which it clearly does).

Comment: @MHOOS Yes, at schema level it works, but at xs:choice level it doesn't.

Comment: I updated my answer and added some workaround. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MHOOS Thanks, but in my case, the user provides the xsd, so it's not upon me to add the annotations. In my case I need to parse the annotation from the provided xsd :-/

Comment: @Vytas999 If the XSD file which you read into your XmlSchema is not provided by and you desperately need that XmlSchemaAnnotation property to be populated then you need to add it(after loading the original one of course) using similar method I mentioned in my response update. That should address your issue irrespective of the fact who has provided the original XSD file. Worst comes to worst you are only re-adding(removing then adding) the annotation which should not have been null in the first place.

Comment: @MHOOS Actually I need it to be correctly parsed, but looks like with XmlSchema.Read() this is not possible. 
Your answer helped the most, so You will receive the extra award of 300 points. However I still would need to search for a serious workaround in this case (which I dont like :-) )

Comment: @Vytas999 if you think the answer helped you with your issue please mark[tick] it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into this issue, I have found by reflecting the classes of the System.Xml.Schema namespace that, upon compiling a schemaset, the annotations of  elements are copied to their  children.

So Vytas999 should be able (as I have been able) to find his missing annotation by inspecting the XmlSchemaParticle objects in the XmlSchemaChoice.Items property.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem - I needed to process an XSD provided by external entity and the `Annotation` of `XmlSchemaChoice` was always null.

Elaborating on @Adrian's answers the code I successfully use is below. In my case I traverse the schema from the root down, when I hit `XmlSchemaSequence` I itereate over its Items collection:

```
var index = 0;
foreach (var childObject in sequence.Items)
{
    ExtractElement(childObject, index);
    ++index ;
}
```

When childObject is of type `XmlSchemaChoice` (assuming it is in variable `xmlSchemaChoice`, then instead of

```
// DOES NOT WORK - always null
var choiceAnnotation = xmlSchemaChoice.Annotation
```

I access the Annotation like this:

```
((xmlSchemaChoice.Parent as XmlSchemaSequence)?.Items[index] as XmlSchemaChoice)?.Annotation
```

Would you expect the same result? Well, it is not..

This code is just sample snippet describing accessing the Annotation via Parent's Items, it is NOT general purpose code and might need some adaptation to your exact case.